# How to go to the line inside header

Tags: spacing, fancyhdr

I use \fancyhead inside header-includes like this :

```
\fancyhead[R]{line1 \\\ line2}
```

but that creates a blank before the line2.

If I write `\fancyhead[R]{line1 \\\line2}`
then I get an error message. 
What should I write to get what I want?

Comment: `\fancyhead[R]{line1 \\ line2}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to achieve.
The effect of the three `line 1\\\ line 2` is to:

1. Typeset "line 1"
2. produce a linebreak `\\`
3. produce a space `\` (note the space afterwards)
4. Typeset "line 2"

Generally speaking, in LaTeX the character `\` indicates "here's a command".
In this case the first `\` says to LaTeX to execute the command of name `\` (i.e. the second `\`). The third is saying to execute the command consisting of a space   .

In your second attempt, you wrote `line 1 \\\line 2` which tells LaTeX to execute the commands `\\` and `\line`. Since the second one is probably not defined, you get an error.

Comment: Thanks Bordaigorl. Blabla\\ blibli. ..and I simply get what I want.

Comment: If this answered your question you may consider to mark it as an answer by using the green checkmark.